# asset_sync not calling md5 hashed asset with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-sync

I was wondering if anyone could see anything wrong with my asset_sync config, when uploading to my bucket the original and the md5-hash version are being uploaded, instead of just the hashed version, is this correct?

```
Using: Manifest /tmp/build_9c7add81-9978-4a01-b46b-f9a4c5ef032e/public/assets/manifest.yml
   Overwriting matching file assets/arrow-left-06560809407b138d1da196208f851494.png with custom headers {:cache_control=>"max-age=31536000", :expires=>"Tue, 16 Jun 2015 10:16:23 GMT"}
   Uploading: assets/arrow-left-06560809407b138d1da196208f851494.png
   Overwriting matching file assets/arrow-right-ae6596cd5b8613bc8dc71cac6851f769.png with custom headers {:cache_control=>"max-age=31536000", :expires=>"Tue, 16 Jun 2015 10:16:23 GMT"}
```

Also when trying to call the assets, it is calling the original filename not the md5 hash, so

```
<img src="http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/slider/img-6.jpg">
```

instead of

```
<img src="http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/slider/img-6-06560809407b138d1da196208f851494.jpg">
```

My initializer looks like this

```
if defined?(AssetSync)
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.fog_region = ENV['FOG_REGION']


 config.existing_remote_files = "delete"
 config.gzip_compression = true
 config.manifest = true
 config.custom_headers = { '.*' => { cache_control: 'max-age=31536000', expires: 1.year.from_now.httpdate } }
 end
 end
```

When i deploy to heroku rake:assets precompile is run, but i have run locally aswell so wondering if ,y manifest.yml file is incorrect? can i delete this and create a new one?

If any more info is needed then please let me know

Thanks

EDIT

So i have found the reason why the original file and the finger printed asset gets created

"Rails 3 by default compiles once to generate fingerprinted assets, and once to generate non-fingerprinted assets (the fingerprinted ones have the MD5 hash in the filename).

You can use the turbo-sprockets-rails3 gem to create both from one compilation.

In Rails 4, this functionality was extracted into the sprockets-rails gem and the behavior was changed, so the double compilation does not happen in Rails 4."

At this stage though i still dont know why the finger printed asset is not being called